# Why does my Angular POST request for PHP file return 404?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, http-status-code-404

I posted the code for my `index.html`, `app.js` and `insert.php`. 
The dependencies installed are **express**, **mysql** and **morgan**.

In my folder I have

- /node_modules
- app.js
- index.html
- insert.php
- package.json

I have a WAMP local server running in the background. phpMyadmin's username is root and password is blank, by default. I've set up a database called `storestuff` with a table in it named `thestuff` which has two columns `title` and `content`.

So I run `node app.js` in the terminal and then get 
`Server running on port 3000.` 
`Connected successfully to the database`.

Now, I go to visit ***localhost:3000***

When the page loads, terminal shows `GET / 304 20.635 ms - -` which means the page loaded correctly.

I've also inserted some dummy data into the MySQL `storestuff` database using phpMyAdmin for testing purposes. Visiting ***localhost:3000/load*** which is a route set up in `app.js`, terminal shows `GET /load 200 16.382 ms - -`
which shows in the browser, a page with JSON data which is indeed the dummy data I had inserted and http code 200 means the GET request worked properly.

When I fill out the `title` field and the `content` field and press submit, terminal shows `POST /insert.php 404 2.949 ms - 150` which I don't understand because `insert.php` is in the same folder as `index.html`.

---

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro">
  </head>

  <body>
    <font face="Source Sans Pro">
      <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
        <h1> Hello world! </h1>
        <form>
          Title <input type="text" ng-model="title"><br>
          Content <input type="text" ng-model="content"><br>
          <input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="insertdata()">
        </form>
        <script>
          var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
          app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.insertdata = function() {
              $http.post('insert.php', {
                'title':$scope.title,
                'content':$scope.content
              })
              .then(function(data) {
                console.log("Data inserted into the MySQL database successfully.");
              });
            }
          });
        </script>
      </div>
    </font>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var app = express();
app.use(morgan('dev'));

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'storestuff'
});

connection.connect(function(error) {
    if(error) console.log("Problem connecting to MySQL: " + error);
    else console.log("Connected successfully to the database");
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/load', function(req, res) {
    connection.query("SELECT * from thestuff", function(err, rows) {
        if(err) console.log("SELECT from thestuff... did not work: " + err);
        else res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server running on port 3000.");
});
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php
  $data = json.decode(file_get_content('php://input'));
  $title = mysql_real_escape_string($data->title);
  $content = mysql_real_escape_string($data->content);
  mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
  mysql_select_db('storestuff');
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO thestuff('title', 'content') VALUES('".$title"', '".$content"')");
?>
```

Comment: have you tried with `$http.post('http://localhost/insert.php')`

Comment: Not Found
The requested URL /insert.php was not found on this server. A typical 404 note :(

Comment: are you getting data on *insert.php*? try `var_dump($data);` on that file

Comment: Could you show me how to use that function? Like where does it go? In the controller? In the insertdata function? In my post request? Sorry.. i'm kinda new to this JavaScript business :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this in the top of your php file

```
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Comment: The terminal showed a `POST /insert.php 404` with my original `$http.post('insert.php')` but when I change to either of your `$http.post('http://localhost/insert.php')` or `$http.post('http://127.0.0.1/insert.php')` pressing submit doesn't even give me an error nor a success, just nothing happens

Comment: and did you tried printing the post data in your php file

Comment: Yes, I did try localhost, sorry I had a typo in my comment reply

Comment: Well, it never gets to the PHP file so printing the data there doesn't output anything in my terminal nor the chrome console

Comment: go to the network part from inspect on your browser. then see what it is showing when you click on submit button

Comment: you need to allow cross origin request in the php file so that angular can access it.

Comment: I got it working thanks to your help with the troubleshooting. I really appreciated you taking the time to help me!

Comment: not a problem bro. just dont forget to thumbs up the answers

Comment: I did but since i'm at 12 reputation, it's an invisible thumbs up haha

Answer (score 1):

try with **headers** property

```
$http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'insert.php',
      data: {'whetever':'data', 'in':'json format'},
      headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
    })
    .then(function(res){
         console.log('successful response', res);
    .catch(function(err) { 
         console.error('Error while post', err);
    });
```

and you can access in on **insert.php**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && empty($_POST)) {
    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);    
    echo $data->whatever;
  }
```

---

**Note:**  you can also you set it globally for all post request within .config block as below

```
myApp.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using node to power your web server. Couple of things: in your app routes you don't have a route for app.post ('/insert.php'), which is the cause of your 404. But node.js itself won't interpret php files for you, so at best it will show the code for the php file. There are plugins you can use or use another web server like nginx in front of the express/nodejs.